# getting error : Found bindings for the following environments: - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 9.x in my ubuntu system

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, node-sass

when i try to start my project in react, i am getting this error , i am using Ubuntu system

```
Found bindings for the following environments:   - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 9.x
```

I am using `node -v : 10.13.0` and `npm -v : 6.11.2`, here i have also attached my package.json file, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "gatsby": "^2.24.48",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-routes": "^1.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.28",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.25",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

I would suggest adding a `.nvmrc` file in the root of your project to avoid this error happen. This is a simple file that fixes the Node version for your project in order to avoid a mismatch between versions and forcing the project to run under a specific version. You just need to add a `.nvmrc` file with this content:

```
v10.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your node_modules and reinstalling. You might also want to check that you don't have something link NVM or and old Node 9 version in your path, that node-sass is picking up while intalling